# SDF Local database Connection error: 40

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce, named-pipes

Hi I am trying to connect to a local SQL Server Compact database (`.sdf`) in a Windows forms project and have been facing this problem for quite some time. I am not allowed to use datasets for the project, all the queries and connections are written in the application.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurredwhile establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured
>   to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Code:

```
SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["restaurant"].ToString());
SqlCommand _Command = _Connection.CreateCommand();

_Connection.Open(); // <- throws exception
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect a Sql Server Compact you need a different set of classes contained in the [namespace SqlServerCe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (SqlCeConnection, SqlCeCommand and so on....)

```
SqlCeConnection _Connection = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["restaurant"].ToString());
SqlCeCommand _Command = _Connection.CreateCommand();
_Connection.Open();
```

of course, you need to reference the assembly that contains the above mentioned classes.

```
 System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll (ADO.NET provider)
```

and add the using statement

```
 using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
```